# "Echo is On" Output to text file blank

Tags: batch-file, syntax

```
for /f %%C in ('Find /V /C "" ^< mamegamelist.txt') do set Count=%%C
  echo The file has %Count% lines.
echo %Count%>gamecount.txt

set /p texte=< mamegamelist.txt  
 echo %texte%>currentgame.txt

set/a played=3379-%Count%
 echo %played%>played.txt

pause
```

Everything works fine except for this line:

```
set/a played=3379-%Count%
 echo %played%>played.txt
```

It evaluates correctly, but it doesn't write out anything to the file.
If I change the arithmetic expression to something like this:

```
set/a played=%Count%+2
 echo %played%>played.txt
```

It will work perfectly fine. I'm pretty sure I don't have any unnecessary spaces anywhere. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell us what numbers you are using.

If `mamegamelist.txt` is empty or has fewer than 10 lines, you get an `echo is off` message from the first redirected `echo`.

A single digit before a redirector redirects an output stream to the file. Somethimes the syntax can be tricky to formulate.

Try

```
>played.txt echo %played%
```

(and follow the bouncing ball for any other possible exactly-1-digit-before-a-redirector instructions, like to `gamecount.txt`)

By placing the redirector at the start of the line, any problem with the syntax is avoided.